# why does this Cubic Spline Error in dimensions appear?

Tags: numbers

```
def f(x):  
    return 1/(1 + (x**2))  

from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline
a = -1      
b = 1
n = 5   
xArray = np.linspace(a,b,n)
yArray = f(xArray)
x = np.linspace(a,b,nPts)
y = CubicSpline(xArray, yArray, x)  
plt.plot(x, y, label="Interpolation, " + str(n) + " points")
```

Im wondering whats the problem in using cubic spline in this way.  The error that I get says there is a wrong dimension?

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (101,) and (1,

Comment: To which line does error point to? and also to make the question clearer, you should mention the constants here.

Comment: Error is pointed to line 10

Comment: The third argument in `y = CubicSpline(xArray, yArray, x)` should be an integer according to the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I see your misunderstanding here roots from misinterpretation of the 'extrapolate' keyword, to quote the documentation of CubicSpline

> **extrapolate{bool, ‘periodic’, None}, optional**
> If *bool*, determines whether to extrapolate to out-of-bounds points
> based on first and last intervals, or to return NaNs. If ‘periodic’,
> periodic extrapolation is used. If None (default), extrapolate is set
> to ‘periodic’ for bc_type='periodic' and to True otherwise.

is a boolean and not the list of points for which you want to interpolate and or extrapolate.

The correct usage is to fit a CubicSpline first and then use it to interpolate or extrapolate

```py
def f(x):  
    return 1/(1 + (x**2))  

from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


a = -1      
b = 1
n = 5   
xArray = np.linspace(a,b,n)
yArray = f(xArray)
x = np.linspace(a,b,101)
cs = CubicSpline(xArray, yArray, True)  # fit a cubic spline
y = cs(x) # interpolate/extrapolate
plt.plot(x, y, label="Interpolation, " + str(n) + " points")
plt.show()
```

The above code will work